# Synchronisation between two groups of operations

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

There's a `lock` that provides exclusive access to a section or resource for everyone. And there's `ReaderWriterLock(Slim)` that provides shared access to all readers and exclusive access to each writer.

What I'm looking for is a synchronisation method to allow shared access to group A and shared access to group B, but not any A and B at the same time. In terms of the reader/writer lock, that would be an arbitrary number of readers, or an arbitrary number of writers, but no reader and writer concurrently.

Another way to explain it may be a **road junction with traffic lights**. Only one side has green. Everyone from this side may pass the junction. As soon as someone is queuing on a different side, the green turns red. Nobody can enter the junction anymore. And only after everybody has left the junction, the next waiting side gets green and everybody from that side may pass.

Is there a suitable solution for that in the .NET Framework? Or what parts would I use to accomplish that?

Semaphores limit the number of users on a single resource but provide no coordination of multiple resources. I don't know any other usable classes right now.

#### What is it good for?

I'm working on a PubSub system (publish/subscribe) with the possibility of delivering past published messages at subscription time. Subscribe and unsubscribe operations can run in parallel, they are updating internal registration data and subscribe operations also read from the message buffer to determine what past messages to send out to the new subscriber. Publish operations are only reading the registration data but add new items to the message buffer and send them to subscribers. Either (un)sub or pub operations may run in parallel, but not both types. This is necessary to prevent published messages to be sent twice (during sub and then pub), and also to prevent messages to be lost (between sub and pub).

#### Sample code

I've tried solving it but couldn't find a solution. Here's my current draft code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class MultiStateLock
{
    // The current confirmed state
    private int currentState;
    // The state somebody is waiting to enter
    private int awaitedState;
    // The number of callers in the current state
    private int enteredCount;

    // Enters a state. Blocks until the state is switched.
    public void Wait(int state)
    {
        // Is the current state not what we want to enter?
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        if (currentState != state)
        {
            var spinWait = new SpinWait();
            // Is some other state currently being awaited? If not, await the new state
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref awaitedState, state, 0) != 0 && awaitedState != state)
            {
                spinWait.SpinOnce();
            }
            // Is somebody else still entered in another state?
            // TODO: These two variables need some synchronisation, without blocking Leave()
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            while (currentState != state && enteredCount > 0)
            {
                spinWait.SpinOnce();
                Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            }
            // Switch the current state
            currentState = state;
            // Let others await another state
            awaitedState = 0;
        }
        // Say we're in the state
        // TODO: This may only be done if currentState wasn't already changed again
        Interlocked.Increment(ref enteredCount);
    }

    // Leaves the entered state.
    public void Leave()
    {
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        if (enteredCount <= 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot leave the state that wasn't entered.");
        // NOTE: Maybe the state to be left could be verified, too.
        //       Or maybe this check could be removed altogether if it's not reliable.
        //       They shouldn't be needed in correct implementations.

        // Say we're out of the state. Were we the last in this state?
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref enteredCount) == 0)
        {
            // Let others switch to their awaited state
            // TODO: This may only be done if enteredCount wasn't already incremented again
            //       (and effectively currentState hasn't changed)
            currentState = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to let as many callers into the same state as wish to. As soon as any caller wants to enter a different state, all new callers will have to wait. When all callers have left their state (so nobody is in any state anymore for a brief moment), the first awaitor may enter their state, and all who were waiting for the same state may follow along.

I haven't even dared trying it out. I know there are missing synchronisations in it, just by thinking it through. See the TODO and NOTE comments. I could just put a `lock` around both `Enter` and `Leave` but since `Enter` will wait, it will block any calls to `Leave` while waiting for `Leave` to run. This will be a deadlock.

I'm intentionally not using `volatile` fields as they [may be improperly synchronised](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility) and I won't fully understand that.

Comment: What's the business requirement you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've updated the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity In case you're interested, I have also added some non-working draft code to further specify my intent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might help. It lets any members of a group share a resource at the same time, but excludes any other groups. When they are finished the other group can use the resource. Test program included.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] groups = new [] {"A", "B"};
        ReadersMonitor readersMonitor = new ReadersMonitor(groups);
        List<Thread> readers = new List<Thread>();
        
        // Create threads for groups
        foreach (string group in groups) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread readerThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    readersMonitor.StartRead(group);
                    // Perform read operation on shared resource
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading shared resource. Group " + group + ".");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulating some read operation
                    readersMonitor.EndRead(group);
                });
                readers.Add(readerThread);
            }
        }

        // Start all the threads
        foreach (Thread t in readers) {
            t.Start();
        }

        // Wait for all threads to finish
        foreach (Thread t in readers) {
            t.Join();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All threads finished");
    }
}

public class ReadersMonitor
{
    // used to store how many group members are using the shared resource at any given time
    private Dictionary<string, int> readers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    
    // initialise each group with a count of 0 current readers
    public ReadersMonitor(string[] groups) {
        foreach (string g in groups) {
            readers.Add(g, 0);
        }
    }

    // Start Read routine
    public void StartRead(string group)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            // while there are any OTHER groups reading, wait, otherwise continue
            while (readers.Any(kv => kv.Key != group && kv.Value > 0))
            {
                try
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(this);
                }
                catch { /* handle/report interrupt exception here */ }
            }
            // increment the number of group members reading
            readers[group]++; 
        }
    }

    // End Read routine
    public void EndRead(string group)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            // decrement the number of group members reading
            readers[group]--; 
            // if no more group members reading, then wake up all threads
            if (readers[group] == 0)
                Monitor.PulseAll(this); 
        }
    }
}
```